# Why is Sanji wanted alive only?

Tags: one-piece

In One Piece manga chapter 801, all the members of the Straw Hat Crew have gotten new bounties on their heads, being shown on those wanted posters. Do you guys have any ideas as to why Sanji's poster only stated `wanted: alive only`? What makes him so special that the government wants him alive?

[image]

Comment: As for now, this is unknown, but many believe Sanji to be of Tenryubito or noble decent, that's why the WG wants him alive. For example when he called himself "Mr. Prince", many believe that to be foreshadowing of him actually being a prince. That's why they think Oda deliberately left his face out of the first bounty poster, not just as a gag, but to prevent people in the OP world from finding out early in the story. It might have left plotholes otherwise.

Comment: @PeterRaeves yes we don't know the true answert jet, but i think there are also enough hints about his past to talk about it. It's not like there are no hints at all.

Comment: @Nube1 I added the actual poster. If you think it is too much, feel free to remove it again.

Comment: I was thinking that the Marineford put only alive on Sanji's bounty because they are not sure if he existed on the first place. Most of the time Sanji acts alone (plus his missing picture on his first bounty, the 2nd one his back was captured on photo, and now a perverted picture) which makes him suspicious.

Comment: if he doesn't exists it's quite hard to catch him alive.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I also thought about this question and I have to agree that at the moment we can only guess what is the reason behind everything with Sanji.

Here are some facts:

- Sanji is the only crew member about whom, we know nothing about (his family and his hometown). We just know he is from the North Blue.
- Sanji has a very noble behavior and acts like a gentleman, which could be because of his education.
- Sanji calls himself "Mr. Prince" in little garden.

[image]

- Zoro calls him "Prince of idiots" during the fight with Foxy.
- Sanji's following quote is also very suspicious:

[image]

- Another point is that Sanji mentioned he was born in the North Blue and knew the land "Noland". Additionally, he wore a red-white hat two times (also in his zombie form), which have the same color as the buildings in the Lvneel Kingodm.

[image][image]

And these are just a few clues about Sanji. It seems obvious that Sanji's history must be quite interesting. It's possible that Sanji has some secret information which the Marines need, or he is an aristocrat, or maybe even a World Noble whom they want to get back alive.

Additionally, I remembered this video with lots of speculation about Sanji.
It's  very interesting.
[**Enjoy.**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jU2YTDD-vnI)

Comment: That has now become cleared in the recent chapters

Answer (score 5):

This was unknown when you asked, but later in chapter 812 we learn a bit. Along the line, up to 875, we get the following conclusion.

> Sanji's dad did that. It is because he wants to capture him to marry one of Big Mom's daughters. The reason why Sanji was needed by his father who told him before "Don't you ever consider yourself my offspring again" is because whoever marries Big Mom's daughter becomes her pet. No Vinsmoke wants that. They just want an aliance with her. So his father realizes he had his old "failure of a son" and asked for that condition for the bounty. Before then, Sanji's "gentleman attitude" is a bit not like his father wanted, so he is locked up in a cell and runs away.

Answer (score -1):

What came to mind was that it would be something to do with his past. With his first wanted poster, the camera had the lens cap on, so there was no picture and so few people really knew who Black Leg Sanji really looked like. But with the new one, the picture finally came across some high up in the government and finally recognize Adult Sanji and child Sanji. And this person being someone with some pull was able to change the bounty to Alive only. But who could this person be?? One idea was that someone that was on the ship that Orbit, that Sanji was on before Zeff and the Cook pirates attacked. Myabe this person felt guilty about Sanji being tossed overboard and not being able to help him, wants to try to help him change his way.

or maybe some female navy officer saw Sanjis picture and flip out, the same way he flips out when he sees any girl. And now she wants sanji for herself.

Comment: I think that's the really the worst hypothesis. How can anyone from Orbit have such authority? And the thing about the marine officer is worse; she'd be punished for that cause sanji is a pirate